# How to write template literal that contains javascript comments in JSDoc without breaking format?

Tags: javascript, typescript, escaping, jsdoc

I want to document javascript function using JSDoc with some `@example`, but it breaks the JSDoc.

The code example I want looks like this (the version what I want):

```js
stripJSDoc(`/**
* Hello
*/

function Hello();

/**
* World
*/

function World();`)

// => ['Hello', 'World']
```

And I will insert above into below.

```js
/**
 * Strip JSDoc text from given string.
 *
 * @example
 *
 * // I will insert above example code here.
 * 
 */

function stripJSDoc();
```

Now, I'm already inserted, the JSDoc format is broken.

```js
/**
 * Strip JSDoc text from given string.
 *
 * @example
 *
 * stripJSDoc(`/**
 * * Hello
 * */
 * 
 * function Hello();
 * 
 * /**
 * * World
 * */
 * 
 * function World();`)
 * 
 * // => ['Hello', 'World']
 * 
 */

function stripJSDoc();
```

As you can see, the format is now broken, I can escape some character, but then VSCode hinting will be broken.

Escaping code:

```js
/**
 * Strip JSDoc text from given string.
 *
 * @example
 *
 * stripJSDoc(`/**
 * * Hello
 * *\/
 * 
 * function Hello();
 * 
 * /**
 * * World
 * *\/
 * 
 * function World();`)
 * 
 * // => ['Hello', 'World']
 * 
 */

function stripJSDoc();
```

Now VSCode is not showing the right documentation:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like there might be a couple of suggestions on this bug: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you must escape `*/` in the example blocks of jsdocs. This is required since JavaScript does not support nested multiline comments

The leading stars in the hover message is a [known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23517) that you cannot work around. It is scheduled to be fixed in TypeScript 3.5, which will not be picked up by VS Code until May. Once the bug is fixed, you can upgrade your TypeScript version in VSCode by following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions). (TypeScript powers VS Code's JavaScript support)